# How can I load Bootstrap CSS properly into my webpage?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have written the code below but the CSS is not fully working. Any suggestions on how I can fix this issue? Thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="display-4">Awesome!</h1>
      <p class="lead">You've been successfully signed up to the Newsletter :)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is not working? I tried it and it works. Can you be more specific, please?

Comment: As you can see in the demo above, this works fine. Please see [ask] and revise your post to be more clear.